# How to insert a cell value in a specific range?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to copy a specific value from a cell and then, insert a new column where all the records must to have the value I copied in the beigining, (that value is the date from the file)

I could insert the new column with the value copied in all the records of it,

The problem is that I need to copy the cell value in all the rows from a specific range that is dinamic, but with my actual code I fill out all the rows until the last excel row and not just the specific range

Details

inicio = start of range variable
fin = end of range variable

My code is

```
    Dim inicio As String
    Dim fin As String

    Cells.Find(What:="TOTAL GENERAL").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    inicio = ActiveCell.row
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    fin = ActiveCell.row

    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.Copy
```

I was triying  to use something like this in mi code but it did not work

```
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert.Range(ActiveCell, fin - 1).EntireColumn.Insert
```

I hope you can help me, thanks a lot

Comment: The new column must be to the right or to the left of the inicio and fin column?

Comment: hi @EvilBlueMonkey the column must be to the left :)

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to use my range variables instead a fixed column or row index

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
Sub NewColumn()

    'Declarations.
    Dim RngInicio As Range
    Dim RngFin As Range
    Dim DatDate As Date

    'Setting variables.
    Set RngInicio = Cells.Find(What:="TOTAL GENERAL").End(xlDown)
    Set RngFin = RngInicio.End(xlDown)
    DatDate = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Value

    'Inserting column.
    RngInicio.EntireColumn.Insert

    'Filling desired cells of the new column.
    Range(RngInicio, RngFin).Offset(0, -1).Value = DatDate

End Sub
```

Tell me if it works for you, if you need any other explanations or improvement. By the way: try to avoid selecting the ranges (or objects) you need in your code. ;)